# Is の absolutely necessary in the following sentence?

Tags: particle-の

> 友達が教えてくれた**の**と同じようにカレーライスを作ったら、とても美味しく出来た。

The sentence appears in my Japanese textbook. To me, it sounds natural to join くれた with と同じ directly, but I don't know if it's also correct:

> 友達が教えてくれたと同じように…

What is the function of this の here, and is it absolutely necessary?

よろしくお願いします

Comment: I see you rejected my edit. Please understand it was a necessary and universally practiced edit across the SE network. It seems you always include a "Thank you" or "よろしくお願いします" in your question. While it is a nice gesture, you should keep in mind that the Stack Exchange consensus is leave out fluff, and this site practices the same idea. Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/) and [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/820/). Phatic expressions should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's absolutely necessary. 同じ is a [special adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30574/5010) and thus cannot be "joined" using と. This と is a "comparison target marker" explained in the following questoins:

- [How is と used in these sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57038/5010) (See the last half of Chocolate's answer)
- [What about this combination of と and や](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52559/5010)

Therefore, the nominalization using の is mandatory. It is also possible to interpret this の as a pronoun meaning "the one". That is, 友達が教えてくれたのと同じように can be translated either as "like my friend taught" and "like the one my friend taught".

Comment: I was just about to comment that the OP (probably accidentally) is asking about two separate constructs. I was certain that the version with と was wrong, but they also ask about joining くれた with 同じ **directly**, which I was also pretty sure was wrong, but was less certain about.

Comment: @user3856370 If you mean 友達が教えてくれたと同じように, this is ungrammatical. 友達が教えてくれたように is fine.

Comment: Yes, I meant 友達が教えてくれた同じように. That's potentially what the OP was asking about. I'm happy that this is grammatical, but is it correct? Does it have the same meaning as 友達が教えてくれたのと同じように?

Comment: @user3856370 教えたように and 教えたのと同じように are correct. 教えたのとように and 教えたと同じように are wrong.

Comment: Argh, sorry I keep misreading/mistyping all these variants. The version I'm asking about is くれた同じように; joining くれた and 同じように directly with nothing in between. I'm asking because this is what the OP asks in the second sentence. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: @user3856370, actually I was only thinking of joining くれた and と同じ in my head, but I forgot to add the と in my explanation. Sorry about that.