# く usage in 場所は昨年と同じく、たから市民会館ホールです

Tags: sentence, grammar

> 本年もまたお願いいたした**く**、ご連絡申し上げました。
>
> 場所は昨年と同じ**く**、たから市民会館ホールです。

What is the use of く here?

I think it is something like conjugating the verb to ます form then removing ます to connect sentences.

For example:

> 交通ルールを守り、安全運転をしましょう.
>   Let's follow the rule and drive safely.

But, in the sentences I mentioned above, it's an い-adjective and a な-adjective (お願いいたしたい and 同じ). So, I would like to inquire about how this structure is formed.

Is it:

Verb = conjugate verb to ます form then remove ます

い-adjective = conjugate to くて and remove て

な-adjective/Noun = add く after

PS. I got some great answers here [Removal of て in Japanese novels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/removal-of-%e3%81%a6-in-japanese-novels/70324#70324)　**but I'm not sure about this 同じく.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/380/about-%e5%90%8c%e3%81%8a%e3%81%aa%e3%81%98-and-%e5%90%8c%e3%81%8a%e3%81%aa%e3%81%98%e3%81%8f

Comment: Yes. Appreciate your help. Thank you.