で as です or condition?

A: 美味しくなかった？
B: いつもと同じでおいしいよ。

In this sentence does the で function as manner/condition for the rest of the sentence indicating reason? "By being in the same way like always it tastes good"?
Or does it function as a copula for です?

It's a copula, i.e., the te-form of だ.
同じで cannot adverbially modify a verb or an adjective:

❌いつもと同じで家を出た。
✅いつもと同じように家を出た。
I left home as usual.


I see, is there a general framework for why this doesn't work adverbial? Just so that I can catch it more easily next time.

@HoodIntercooledSubaru In this case, I think all we can do is remember how to say "in the same way; equally; similarly" in Japanese...

Yeah had a feeling that was the case. Thanks for the answer still :)

@HoodIntercooledSubaru You may be interested in this question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16269/5010

Appreciate the link! After I read it, it also put me somewhat at ease and made me think about not trying to over analyze too much. I was wondering as a last reply to this thread (since I don't want to clutter the stack site with too many questions) when someone says something like ''私の負けでいいから…'' would this imply a reluctant/neutral choice like ''寿司でいい'' or does this function as a copula as well?

@HoodIntercooledSubaru Those で are the same, and they're particles. 寿司でいい does not mean "It's sushi, and it's good".

@HoodIntercooledSubaru 同じく could be used adverbially... 同じ was originally a regular adjective, but it lost almost all of its inflection... See also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/380.
